# Check whether day is specified in a date string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date

Test case scenario - User clicks on one of two links: `2012/10`, or `2012/10/15`.

I need to know whether the DAY is specified within the link. I am already stripping the rest of the link (except above) out of my URL, am I am passing the value to an AJAX request to change days on an archive page.

I can do this in either JS or PHP - is checking against the regex `/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/` the only approach to seeing if the day was specified or not?

Comment: don't know if it is the only way(don't have another one now) but seems a viable way(having in mind it checks the format). If you tested and it works, just be happy, you found your solution.

Comment: What about resolving the issue with inconsistent links?

Comment: Not, a silly way is to check the size of the result. If you have 2 digits less...

Comment: You could simply `count(explode("/", $str))` and then split it into components then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do this if you always get this format: 2012/10 or 2012/10/15

```
if( str.split("/").length == 3 ) { }
```

But than there is no guaranty it will be numbers. If you want to be sure they are numbers you do need that kind of regex to match the String.

Comment: You may be onto something. I am already *for sure* receiving a ####/## format, so this may be the simplest approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could explode the date by the "/" delimiter, then count the items:

```
$str = "2012/10";
$str2 = "2012/10/5";

echo count(explode("/", $str)); // 2
echo count(explode("/", $str2)); // 3
```

Or, turn it into a function:

```
<?php
function getDateParts($date) {
  $date = explode("/", $date);
  $y = !empty($date[0]) ? $date[0] : date("Y");
  $m = !empty($date[1]) ? $date[1] : date("m");
  $d = !empty($date[2]) ? $date[2] : date("d");
  return array($y, $m, $d);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the `PHP` response! Similar to @Niels response.

Comment: if I were to create it as a function, I'd suggest keying the values.. `array( 'year' => $y, 'month' => $m, 'day' => $d )`

Comment: ^ +1; I was going to do that, but my fingers went lazy :(

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a regex, it is a great way of testing this sort of thing. Alternatively, you can `split/implode` the string on `/`, you will have an array of 3 strings (hopefully) which you can then test. I'd probably use that technique if I was going to do work with it later.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way is to check the length of the string!
In fact, you need to distinguish between: yyyy/mm/dd (which is 10 characters long) and yyyy/mm (which is 7 characters).

```
if(strlen($str) > 7) {
    // Contains day
}
else {
    // Does not contain day
}
```

This will work EVEN if you do not use leading zeros!
In fact:

```
2013/7/6 -> 8 characters (> 7 -> success)
2013/7 -> 6 characters (< 7 -> success)
```

This is certainly the fastest code too, as it does not require PHP to iterate over the whole string (as using explode() does).